# Display tested URL when running Selenium test using vstest.console.exe tool

Tags: c#, selenium, jenkins, automated-tests

**Context**

I configured Jenkins job which executes Selenium C# tests.
When building a job, I must provide two values:

- branch to build my solution
- URL which should be tested

**Detailed description**

Jenkins performs the following steps:

- checkout selected branch
- replace URL stored in AppSettings with URL provided by the user ("TestedURL")
- build solution
- execute [vstest.console.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155800.aspx) tool (which comes with Visual Studio 2012, exists in the following path: "Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow") as follows:

  vstest.console.exe "c:\myProject\bin\Debug\myProject.Test.dll"

**Question**

I would like to ensure that proper URL is tested: I would like to display URL in console output of the Jenkins/vstest.console.exe output.

I amended my code following different answers on StackOverflow.

URL is visible in test output directly from Visual Studio. Unfortunately, I still don't see any testing URL in vstest.console.exe/Jenkins output.

How to display URL in output (how to modify printMessage method)?

My code is as follows:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace My.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyTests
    {
        IWebDriver driver;
        string baseURL;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            // URL is replaced by the value provided in Jenkins
            baseURL = config.AppSettings.Settings["TestedURL"].Value;
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL);
            printMessage(string.Format("Tested URL: '{0}'", baseURL));
        }

        private TestContext testContextInstance;
        /// <summary>
        ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
        ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
        ///</summary>
        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get
            {
                return testContextInstance;
            }
            set
            {
                testContextInstance = value;
            }
        }

        private void printMessage(string message)
        {
            // Method should display custom message in both Visual Studio output and Jenkins (vstest.console.exe) output
            Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
            Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
            Trace.WriteLine(message);
            Debug.WriteLine(message);
            TestContext.WriteLine(message);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't find direct solution, I've found a workaround.

vstest.console.exe has */logger:trx* option which generates file with .trx extension. Mentioned file is an xml which contains test results together with Std output. I noticed that when I use my printmessage within test methods, messages are there (in Std output in trx file).

Let me provide part of generated .trx file:

```
<Output>
    <StdOut>Tested URL was 'http://someURL'

Debug Trace:
Tested URL: 'http://someURL'
Trying to log into as 'Incorrect account'

TestContext Messages:
Tested URL: 'http://someURL'
Trying to log into as 'Incorrect account'</StdOut>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
```

There are some tool which allows conversion of .trx to .html.
Thus Jenkins can show in console output link to the test results.

---

*BUT*

I have problem, because I can't find tool which works properly and shows Std output in generated html file.
Since that, I wrote following Powershell code:

```
# set $inputTRXFile, $outputHTMLFile before running following lines
$results = ([xml] (Get-Content $inputTRXFile)).TestRun.Results.UnitTestResult
$results | select testname,outcome,duration, @{Name="Output";Expression={$_.Output.InnerText}} | ConvertTo-HTML -head $a -title "Test results" | Out-File $outputHTMLFile
```